# Function that returns pointer, when imported in separate file, return number instead of object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers

I have a file called, runner.py, which has a lot of functions that make calls to a market DLL.

```
#Imports para execução da DLL
import time
import gc
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import UINT
import struct
from datetime import*
import sys
import functions
from threading import Thread

rotPassword = '' 
accountID   = '' 
corretora   = '' 

profit_dll = WinDLL('./ProfitDLL64.dll')
profit_dll.argtypes  = None

def printPosition():
    global profit_dll
    global corretora, accountID

    asset = 'asset'
    bolsa = 'f'
    thisCorretora = corretora
    acc_id = accountID    
    priceToReturn = 0

    result = profit_dll.GetPosition(c_wchar_p(str(acc_id)), c_wchar_p(str(thisCorretora)), c_wchar_p(asset), c_wchar_p(bolsa))

    print(f'here {result}')    
    return result
    
    n_qtd = result[0]

    if (n_qtd == 0):
        print('Nao ha posicao para esse ativo')        
        return priceToReturn
    else:
        n_tam = result[1]       

        arr = cast(result, POINTER(c_char))
        frame = bytearray()
        for i in range(n_tam):
            c = arr[i]
            frame.append(c[0])
        
        start = 8

        for i in range(n_qtd):
            corretora_id = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            acc_id_length = struct.unpack('h', frame[start:start+2])[0]
            start += 2
            account_id = frame[start:start+acc_id_length]
            start += acc_id_length

            titular_length = struct.unpack('h', frame[start:start+2])[0]
            start += 2
            titular = frame[start:start+titular_length]
            start += titular_length

            ticker_length = struct.unpack('h', frame[start:start+2])[0]
            start += 2
            ticker = frame[start:start+ticker_length]
            start += ticker_length

            intraday_pos = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            price = struct.unpack('d', frame[start:start + 8])[0]       
            priceToReturn = str(price)     
            start += 8

            avg_sell_price = struct.unpack('d', frame[start:start + 8])[0]
            start += 8

            sell_qtd = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            avg_buy_price = struct.unpack('d', frame[start:start + 8])[0]
            start += 8

            buy_qtd = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            custody_d1 = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            custody_d2 = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            custody_d3 = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            blocked = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            pending = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            allocated = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            provisioned = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            qtd_position = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            available = struct.unpack('i', frame[start:start+4])[0]
            start += 4

            print(f"Corretora: {corretora_id}, Titular: {str(titular)}, Ticker: {str(ticker)}, Price: {price}, AvgSellPrice: {avg_sell_price}, AvgBuyPrice: {avg_buy_price}, SellQtd: {sell_qtd}, BuyQtd: {buy_qtd}")

        return priceToReturn

def dllStart():    
    try:
        global profit_dll
        key = input("Chave de acesso: ")
        user = input("Usuário: ") # preencher com usuário da conta (email ou documento)
        password = input("Senha: ") # preencher com senha da conta
        
        bRoteamento = True
        
        if bRoteamento :            
            result = profit_dll.DLLInitializeLogin(c_wchar_p(key), c_wchar_p(user), c_wchar_p(password), stateCallback, historyCallBack, orderChangeCallBack, accountCallback,
                                              newTradeCallback, newDailyCallback, priceBookCallback,
                                              offerBookCallback, newHistoryCallback, progressCallBack, newTinyBookCallBack)
        else :
            result = profit_dll.DLLInitializeMarketLogin(c_wchar_p(key), c_wchar_p(user), c_wchar_p(password), stateCallback, newTradeCallback, newDailyCallback, priceBookCallback,
                                                 offerBookCallback, newHistoryCallback, progressCallBack, newTinyBookCallBack)

        profit_dll.SendSellOrder.restype = c_longlong
        profit_dll.SendBuyOrder.restype = c_longlong
        profit_dll.SendStopBuyOrder.restype = c_longlong
        profit_dll.SendStopSellOrder.restype = c_longlong
        profit_dll.SendZeroPosition.restype = c_longlong
        profit_dll.GetAgentNameByID.restype = c_wchar_p
        profit_dll.GetAgentShortNameByID.restype = c_wchar_p
        profit_dll.GetPosition.restype = POINTER(c_int)
        profit_dll.SendMarketSellOrder.restype = c_longlong
        profit_dll.SendMarketBuyOrder.restype = c_longlong

        print('DLLInitialize: ' + str(result))
        wait_login()
      
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    try:
        dllStart()

        strInput = ''        

        while strInput != "exit":
            strInput = input('Insira o comando: ')
            if strInput == 'subscribe':
                subscribeTicker()
            elif strInput == 'unsubscribe':
                unsubscribeTicker()
            elif strInput == 'offerbook':
                subscribeOffer()
            elif strInput == 'position':
                printPosition()
            elif strInput == 'lastAdjusted':
                printLastAdjusted()
            elif strInput == 'buystop' :
                buyStopOrder()
            elif strInput == 'sellstop':
                sellStopOrder()
            elif strInput == 'cancel':
                cancelOrder()
            elif strInput == 'changeOrder':
                changeOrder()
            elif strInput == 'cancelAllOrders':
                cancelAllOrders()
            elif strInput == 'getOrders':
                getOrders()
            elif strInput == 'getOrder':
                getOrder()
            elif strInput == 'selectOrder':
                selectOrder()
            elif strInput == 'cancelOrder':
                cancelOrder()
            elif strInput == 'getOrderProfitID':
                getOrderProfitID()
            elif strInput == 'getAllTickersByStock':
                getAllTickersByStock()           
            elif strInput == 'getOld':
                getSerieHistory()        
            elif strInput == 'account':
                getAccount()         
            elif strInput == 'myBuy':
                sendBuyOrder()               
    except KeyboardInterrupt:                
        pass
```

The correct log that I get when calling:

```
<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_long object at 0x000001714E9CABC0>
```

When running directly the `runner.py` and calling `printPosition()`, everything works fine and it returns what I need (the object above).
Although, I need to import this printPosition in a separate file to make a call for it. When performing so, I received a number only and not the object I needed.

```
import socket, base64
import re
import sys
from operator import neg
from datetime import datetime
import profitrunner
import time
import gc
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import UINT
import struct

def calculate_pos():
    memory_address = profitrunner.printPosition()       

    print(heapPosition)

    # I though on doing but did not work:  
  
    arr = cast(memory_address, POINTER(c_char))
```

The logs from this:

```
2015042512
2015042656
2015042800
2015042944
2015043088
2015043232
```

The documentation from `GetPosition` gives is the follwing:

```
Function that returns the position for a given ticker. Returns a data structure specified below. With full size (90 + N + T + K) bytes:

function GetPosition(
    pwcIDAccount   : PWideChar;
    pwcIDCorretora : PWideChar;
    pwcTicker      : PWideChar;
    pwcBolsa       : PWideChar) : Pointer; stdcall;
```

[image]

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Looks like a misuse of [tag:ctypes] without the code showing its setup to call DLL functions.

Comment: The setup for calling the function, is in the `result`, and the function type is the last code block, I don't have acess to the DLL itself

Comment: Did you set `.restype` and `.argtypes` for the function correctly?  Show a [mcve] (read the link).

Comment: You get “just a number” if `.restype` isn’t set properly. I don’t see it set at all, and I’m surprised that you would get a ctypes object without it. This is why I asked for actual code that produces your results not snippets

Comment: I will atempt to create so

Comment: @MarkTolonen ```
#Caminho para a DLL, python tem que ser 32bits
profit_dll = WinDLL('./ProfitDLL64.dll')
profit_dll.argtypes  = None
```
I will attempt to create a minial example

Comment: Set `.argtypes` and `.restype` on each function you use in the DLL.  The default for arguments is generally `c_int` but `bytes` will pass as `c_char_p` and `str` will pass as `wchar_p`.  Return values default to `c_int` so 64-bit values and pointers will be truncated and appear as Python `int`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen i updated the question with some data, see if it helps somehow, I added a return in the printPosition due to it breaking on the result[0] when calling from calculate_pos()

Comment: I added DLL start command, too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256265/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-nilton-schumacher-f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```py
import ctypes as ct

profit_dll = ct.WinDLL('./ProfitDLL64.dll')
profit_dll.GetPosition.argtypes = ct.c_wchar_p, ct.c_wchar_p, ct.c_wchar_p, ct.c_wchar_p
profit_dll.GetPosition.restype = ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)

result = profit_dll.GetPosition(acc_id, thisCorretora, asset, bolsa)
```

The return type is only `Pointer` which isn't descriptive, but in the `.zip` provided in comments the return type is `POINTER(c_int)` so I used that.  No need to wrap every parameter in a C type if `.argtypes` is set properly for the function, but `profitDLL.py` isn't doing that.  Make sure to call `dllStart()` to set the return types, but it's better to set `.argtypes` and `.restype` correctly for every function for better error checking by `ctypes`.

Comment: Here's the link in case you want to have a look:
https://downloadserver-cdn.nelogica.com.br/produtos/bin/DLL/3.0.1.22/ProfitDLL.zip